# Semi-Monthly Maturity Date Calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to find a way to calculate the final due date of a loan using JavaScript that accounts for months with less than 31 or 30 days and operates semi-monthly.

For example, if I have a semi-monthly term of 12 (6 months) and my start_date is 01/31/2015, my final due date should be 6/15/2016.  Any ideas?

Here is what I have for monthly:

```
var addMonths = (function() {
  var counts = {
    normal: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    leap:   [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
  };
  return function(startDate, months) {
    var endYear = startDate.getFullYear() + Math.ceil((months + startDate.getMonth()) / 12) - 1;
    var yearType = ((endYear % 4 == 0) && (endYear % 100 != 0)) || (endYear % 400 == 0) ? 'leap' : 'normal';
    var endMonth = (startDate.getMonth() + months) % 12;
    var endDate = Math.min(startDate.getDate(), counts[yearType][endMonth]);
    return new Date(endYear, endMonth, endDate);
  };
}());

var date = new Date("contractDate");
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var newDate = new Date(year, month, day);

var result = addMonths(newDate, term-1);
```

Comment: Yes.  Plenty of ideas.  What particular part are you stuck on?

Comment: I added the code I am using for monthly.

Comment: Hi @JosephMarikle.  I'm trying a 'contractDate' of 9/1/2015 and a 'term' of 53, but getting the wrong result using the formula above.  Instead of 1/1/2020, it shows 1/1/2019.  Any ideas how this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything you posted is correct 06/15/2016 does not match 6 months from 01/31/2015.

The correct date should be: Friday, July 31, 2015 (07/31/2015)

Heres an example on how to get 6 months from the current date in javascript.

```
function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

var dateStarted = new Date(Date.parse("01/31/2015"))
var dateEnded = dateStarted.getTime();
var termMonths = 6 // Pure Month Count

for(var monthCount = dateStarted.getMonth() + 1; monthCount < dateStarted.getMonth() + (termMonths + 1); monthCount++) { 
    dateEnded += (24*3600000) * getDaysInMonth(monthCount, dateStarted.getFullYear());
}

console.log(new Date(dateEnded))
```

The big thing here is:

```
dateEnded += (24*3600000) * getDaysInMonth(monthCount, dateStarted.getFullYear());
```

So dateStarted is converting the time into milliseconds (unix timestamp).

dateEnded is getting updated with the amount of milliseconds in each month after your start date.

Since there are 3600000 milliseconds in an hour you need to times that by 24 to get the amount of milliseconds that are in a day. Then you need to multiply that number by the amount of days in the month.

After you add all of the months together you need to convert that value into a useable format:

```
console.log(new Date(dateEnded))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The issue here though is that I am trying to solve for semi-monthly.  For example, if I have a term of 2 that is semi-monthly, and your first due date is 1/1/2015, your final due date would be 1/15/2015.  I tried the example above, but it doesn't seem to solve for this correctly. :\

Comment: Use what I gave as a base. Then instead of 3600000 use 1800000. Your still going to need to loop through each month but instead of adding the entire month you just need to add half of it.

Comment: Thanks.  I modified, but here are the results I am getting:

Comment: Start Date: 1/1/15

Term   |   Result  |  Should Be, 
2   |   1/30/2015  |  1/16/2015, 
4   |   3/2/2015   |   2/16/2015, 
5   |   3/17/2015   |   3/1/2015, 

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Bioto.  I've tried a few different options, but can't seem to get it to work.  Any other ideas?